# YADR dotfiles, messed up my Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, dotfiles, iterm2

I recently triend out several dotfile repos, yet i could always undo the changes in my terminal bot not now! I dont know how to reset my terminal to factory defaults.

I tried out most of the things that google offered me.

Basicly I want my terminal to be on factory default settings.

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir ~/.zsh_backup
mv ~/.z* ~/.zsh_backup
```

Got the same issue. This should move all zsh configs to a backup directory. If you use zsh then possibly there are files with a *backup postfix when you do:

```
ls ~/.zsh_backup/.*backup
```

If yes, then just recover the backups.